# Swift: cannot convert value of type <> to expected argument type <> when setting up a selector

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdictionary

I'm getting this error:

> cannot convert value of type nsdictionary to expected argument type string

[image]

Here is my code:

```
let json:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataResponse, options: []) as! NSDictionary
self.performSelector(onMainThread: Selector(updateUIwithJsonResponse), with: json, waitUntilDone: true)
```

`performSelector` is calling this function:

```
func updateUIwithJsonResponse(json:NSDictionary) {
print(json)
}
```

Any of you knows why I'm getting this error?

Comment: 1. Why are you using `NSDictionary` instead of a Swift dictionary? 2. Why are you using `performSelector` instead of `DispatchQueue`?

Comment: @rmaddy, because I don't need a queue. Why do you think it would better using DispatchQueue?

Comment: Using `DispatchQueue.main.async` is much simpler and cleaner. You can simply write the actual code inside the block. No need to mess with selectors and it works with any number and types of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method takes a parameter, so try

`self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(updateUIwithJsonResponse(json:)), with: json, waitUntilDone: true)`

Comment: Why can't remove json: in #selector(updateUIwithJsonResponse(json:)) ?